# Complexity for nested for loops

Tags: c, complexity-theory

I want to find the complexity of the code below.
    I used this code to find the second highest element in the array using sorting.

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
     //some code
   }
}
```

Is the complexity O(2n) or O(n<sup>2</sup>)?

Comment: Its need `2n` iterations, So what it should be **?**

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop

Comment: And which kind of complexity?

Comment: Big Oh notation is NOT as simple as we might believe.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very vast topic. I am just putting my effort to bring it to you. rest you refer some good books for it. My recommendation in `Coreman`.

Complexity :

basic structure of a for loop is

```
for(initialization;condition;updation)
```

in updation we are updating values, so basically we are iterating the loop upto the condition.

so it is like

```
n*(n+1)/2
```

which is basically O(n^2) in your two for loop case.

Estimation of Complexity:

Sometimes it is not easy to get a formula for the complexity of an algorithm. In such cases it may be possible to estimate it by experiment. Counting-variables can be added to the program, incremented when some critical operation is carried out and the final totals printed. The running time can also be measured, either by a stop-watch or better by calling a routine to print the computer system's clock. The complexity might be inferred by examining how such measures vary with the problem size.

The accuracy of timing a program or an operation can be improved by timing a number of executions, perhaps in a loop, and dividing the total time taken by that number. A time-shared computer is used by many people simultaneously. The elapsed time taken by a program depends on the system load. Therefore any timing done on a shared machine must be based on the central processor time devoted to the particular program under study and not on the elapsed time.

Examining differences between adjacent terms in a series can indicate the form of the underlying function that defines the series. A linear function, `T(n)=a*n+b` gives rise to constant difference between `T(n)` and `T(n-1)`:

```
D1(n) = T(n)-T(n-1) = a*n+b-a*(n-1)-b = a
```

A quadratic function `T(n)=a*n2+b*n+c` gives rise to linear first-order differences:

```
D1(n) = T(n)-T(n-1) = a*n2+b*n+c-a*(n-1)2-b*(n-1)-c = 2a*n-a+b
```

which gives rise to constant second-order differences `D2(n) = D1(n)-D1(n-1)`. In general, a polynomial of degree d is revealed by constant `dth-order` differences.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know the solution is to draw a table:

```
Iteration |   i    |   j
----------+--------+-------
    0     |   0    |   0
    0     |   0    |   1
    0     |   0    |   2
    0     |  ...   |  ... 
    0     |  ...   |  ...
    0     |  ...   | n - 1
    1     |   1    |   0
    1     |   1    |   1
    1     |  ...   |  ... 
    1     |  ...   |  ...
    1     |  ...   | n - 1
```

How many times it is executed? That's the answer.. 
If you want to have an intuition you should pick some `n`, run an example.. Then choose another `n` and see what you get, finally you'll conclude what's the answer.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't [approve suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2763311) using backticks for emphasis, but reject or improve them - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why

Answer (score 0):

if "some code" does o(1) then the complexity of this code is O(2n)

that's because the inner code is in complexity of o(n), and we do this loop for 2 times. then it's  O(2n)

Answer (score 0):

Big Oh notation gives order of magnitude estimates, differences in constants really do not affect the magnitude of an algorithm, so O(2n) = 2O(n) = (n).

Similar to 1000 >> 10 = 5.  That is, 1000 is much bigger than 10 and it is just as "bigger" than 5 as it is for 10, even though 10 is twice the value of 5.