# Calculating Time Complexity of Nested Loops

Tags: big-o

Here's a piece of pseudo code that i wanna compute the big-O of it, but i have difficulty to calculate it, does someone can help me? thanks!

```
for i = 1 to p
  for j = i to n
    for a = i to j
      for k = 1 to m
        ;
```

Comment: An aggregation of answers is likely to help here, although you are advised to search first before posting next time. Hope this helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/time-complexity-formula-of-nested-loops http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic600780.files/loop_analysis.pdf In short, look at the type of operations being performed in each nested loop, and get an intuition for how they increase as the number of inputs (to the original function) increase to infinity.

Comment: Where get you stuck? Have you tried to calculate the big-o yourself?