# How to calculate time complexity for this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Compute the complexity of the following Algorithm.

```
i = 1;
while(i < n+1)
{
   j=1
   while(j < n+1) 
   {
      j = j*2
   }
   i++
}
```

Comment: No. *You* compute the complexity of the following Algorithm.

Comment: would  it not be nice if one could post your homework here like that? we can call it getyourhomeworkdone.com but youwontlearnanything.net

Comment: It is not homework.It's sample question..and i dont want the direct answer.My question was how to calculate it..

Comment: Did you follow @adrianus' link? your answer is there

Comment: Yeah i follow and thats why i thanks to him for giving some hints.

Comment: Could you figure it out? Consider accepting my answer if it helped solving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself, in which way does `i` <s>increment</s> grow towards the final value n? How many times will the outer loop run for a given `n`?

The same for the inner loop. I recommend you read through somthing like [this](http://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/time-complexity-of-algorithms) or [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop) and maybe start with some examples:

```
n = 100;
i = 1;
while (i < n+1){
    j = 1;
    while (j < n+1) {
        j = j*2
    }
    i = i+1;
}
```

How many times exactly will both of the loops run?

Comment: That were some hints already. Read through the link provided or do your own google search with `time complexity of nested loops` and tutorials will pop up everywhere (even for your exact problem).