# Mathematical derivation of O(n^3) complexity for general three nested loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, code-complexity

[Time complexity of nested for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop) goes into the mathematical derivation through summation of two loops O(n2) complexity.

I tried an exercise to derive how i can get O(n3) for the following examples of three nested loops.

### Simple three nested loops.

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                 print(i * k * j);
```

Summation is
= (n + n + n + .... + n) + (n + n + n + ... + n) + ... + (n + n + n + ... + n)

= n^2 + n^2 + .... + n^2

n times n^2 = O(n^3)

### Three nested loops not run n times from beginning

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     for(int j = i; j <= n; j++)
         for(int k = j; k <= n; k++)
             print(i *j * k)
```

The above is a pretty common form of nested loops and i believe the summation would be something as follows

= (n + (n -1) + (n -2) + (n - 3) + ... + 1) 
+ ((n -1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) +... + 1) 
+ ((n -2) + (n -3) + (n - 4) + ... + 1) 
+ ... 
+ ((n - (n -2)) + 1)

= n(n - 1) /2 + (n-1) (n -2) / 2 + (n-2)(n-3)/2 + .... + 1

=
*From here i am slightly not sure if my logic is correct . I believe
each of the above evaluate to a polynomial whose greatest value is n2 and as thats what we care about in time complexity, the above equation breaks down to.*

= n^2 + n^2 + n^2 +... +n^2

= which is n times n^2 = O(n^3).

Is my assumption correct?

### Three nested loops not run n times from end

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
         for(int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
             print(i *j * k)
```

If the above was a two nested loop the summation would have been 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n. However, for the three nested occurence i am deducing it to be

= 1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2 + 3 + .... + n)

From here i am not sure how to derive O(n^3) or how the above summation would be further simplified.

Comment: The summation of the first loop is `n*n*n` which is `O(n^3)`, and so is the second. You aren't doing yourself any favours by omitting the exponentiation operator.

Comment: The loops should be in the form (x = 0; x < n; x++) to get n loops. I'm guessing that you're also considering combinations: for(i = 0; i < n-2; i++){ for(j = i+1; j < n-1; j++){ for(k = j+1; k < n; k++){ ... }}}, which is the number of combinations of n things taken 3 at a time.

Comment: Try to estimate how many times the inner loops run on the average.

Comment: The people who downvoted this, would please care to explain?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is maths and not programming.

Comment: @Saad The existing comments are sufficient to explain downvotes. There is no such thing as *O(n3)*. There is however such a thing as *O(n^3).* Do you ever plan to correct your post?

Comment: @PaulHankin It is  rather basic algorithmic complexity theory, and there are many questions about it here.

Comment: I corrected it right away as you can see in the post.

Comment: You've fixed a few occurrences. Not all. Question remains unclear.

Comment: oops.....................

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that:
`1+2+3+...+i =i*(i+1)/2`, the summation above can be written as:
`1*(1+1)/2 + 2*(2+1)/2 + ... + n*(n+1)/2`. 
Obviously `i*(i+1) > i^2`, therefore:

`1*(1+1)/2 + 2*(2+1)/2 + ... + n*(n+1)/2 > (1^2+...+ n^2)/2`, as we know:

`1^2+...+n^2 = n^3/3 + n^2/2 + n/6` (can prove this by induction).

Therefore, the original sum `S` is bigger than:

`n^3/6 + n^2/4 + n/12`, which is `O(n^3)`.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the exact formula is n^3/6 + n^2/2 + n/3. One way to determine this is to do a polynomial curve fit.

Comment: The easy way: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(sum(sum(1,+for+k+%3D+1+to+j),+for+j%3D1+to+i),+for+i+%3D+1+to+n)