# Complexity of nested for loops starting from the last iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, time-complexity, nested-loops

```
function solution(A) {
    var len = A.length;
    cnt = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){
        for (a = i + 1; a < len; a++){
            if (A[i] == A[a]){cnt++;}
            else{continue;}
        }
        if(cnt > 1000000000){return 1000000000;}
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

So this is a code for counting identical pairs of an array, I know that 2 for loops give time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>). Is it always the case? Even if the next iteration goes through only remaining part of the array?

Comment: look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop) duplicate

Comment: Yeah the thing is I don't iterate through the list from the start, like in your suggested link, I iterate n-1 times the second time and so on, does it still mean I get same complexity?

Comment: The link I posted is almost the same just mirror. Just look at it carefully and you'll get it. But anyways, same complexity. 1+2+3+..+n= (n^2 +n)/2 which is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this will be roughly O(1/2n^2) but since constants aren't really that important this will end up being O(n^2)