# What is the complexity for such loop?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Could you please help me to clarify what is the complexity of the following piece of code where I traverse through the "unvisited" items in an array on each step?

```
final int[] arr = {...};
for (int i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[j]);
    }
}
```

I bet it's `O(NlogN)` or `O(N√N)`, where `N` is `arr.length`

Am I right? Could you explain to me why?

I think it's `O(NlogN)` or `O(N√N)` because on each step the "unvisited" part is reduced so it's less than `O(N^2)` but still greater than `O(N)`

Comment: Why don't you explain why you think it's `O(log N)`

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: It's not O(log N), it's n(n+1)/2 => n^2 in short. Where n(n+1)/2 is sum of n natural numbers.

Comment: It is `O(n^2)`. The second loop runs on average `n/2` times, and constant multipliers are ignored.

Comment: You have to think about what the biggest polynomial term would look like if you wrote it out

Comment: Detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526751/5051731)

Comment: *"I bet it's O(logN) or O(√N), where N is arr.length"* - How much?   Seriously dude there is no need to guess.  You can work out the number of iterations performed by analyzing the code and doing some simple (high-school level) algebra to work out a precise formula.  (Try it for yourself. It is a simple exercise ... and I imagine that's what your teacher wants you to do.)

Comment: Every constant value has to be ignored on Big O.
(n^2)/2 can be 1/2 *  n^2. 1/2 must be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your routine prints something like this:

```
arr[0] arr[1] arr[2] ... arr[n]
arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] ... arr[n]
...
arr[n]
```

If the calculation for each step is the printing, then I would say the complexity is `O(n^2)`. Because the number of all the prints is `(length+1)*length/2`.