# Nested For Loop confusion

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am writing a nested For Loop. Trying to setup a break but doesn't seem to work.  Here is what I am trying to do.  As an example:

```
var playersList = sam,tom,jane

var playersDrafted = tom,jane
```

Sam is not found in `playersDrafted`, so I want Sam's name to not have a line strike. Tom and Jane are found in the `playersDrafted`, so I do want there names to have a line strike. The code I've written is returning this:

> sam
>   sam
>   <s>tom</s>
>   tom
>   <s>jane</s>
>   jane

The result should be:

> sam
>   <s>tom</s>
>   <s>jane</s>

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div>
  <table align="center">     
    <? for(var i=0;i<playersList.length;i++){ ?>
        here:
        <? for(var y=0;y<playersDrafted.length;y++){ ?>

             <? if(playersList[i]==playersDrafted[y]) { ?> 
                 <tr>
                   <td style="text-decoration: line-through;"><?= 
playersList[i]; ?></td>                    
                </tr> 
                 <? break here; ?>
             <? } ?>              

        <? } ?>
             <tr>
                <td><?= 
playersList[i]; ?></td>                    
             </tr> 
    <? } ?> 

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: did you consider using `playersDrafted.indexOf(i) > -1`?

Comment: Why do you need the nested loop? Since the names aren't alphabetical, you can just first render all the names not inside `playersDrafted` and then after that all the names inside `playersDrafted`. So two separate loops, not one loop nested into the other. You can even do that with one loop and `Array.includes()` if you don't mind more array lookups. I would probably create a 3rd array to do less lookups, `availableForDraft`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Shilly mentioned, in your case you don't really need 2 nested for loops. Not using 2 nested for loops would also reduce the [complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop) space of your code (if you have very big lists, the difference is not neglectable).

However, as you asked help on using 2 nested for loops I have written this small code in pure Javascript. I added a boolean value `notDrafted` and if the second loop reaches its end without breaking we print out the name of the player not drafted.

```
var playersList = ["sam", "tom", "jane"];

var playersDrafted = ["tom", "jane"];

var notDrafted = true;

for (var i = 0; i < playersList.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j< playersDrafted.length; j++) {
        if(playersList[i]==playersDrafted[j]) {
            console.log(playersList[i] + "with line");
            notDrafted = false;
        }
    }
    if (notDrafted) {
        console.log(playersList[i]);
    }
    notDrafted = true; // reset to not drafted
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, @Eduard, your code works perfectly.  Sorry, I am just starting to teach myself javascript.  I dont understand why I dont need a nested loop.  Can you explain in further detail please?  If I were to write a VB.Net app, this is how I would accomplish it.