# How do I calculate the time complexity of a nested 'for' loop?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

Consider:

```
def fun(n):

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, n, i):
            print (i, “,”, j)
```

I'm having trouble with the nested `for` loop. Is it 2n^2 + 2n + 1?

Comment: Notice the `i` as step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time complexity of nested for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop)

Comment: @CeliusStngher: the above is not an entire duplicate, since here the step is `i`, not `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner loop runs from `1` (inclusive) to `n` (exclusive) in hops of `i`. That thus means that it will make `(n-1)//i` steps.

The outer loop makes `n` runs where `i` ranges from `1` to `n`. We can slighlty overestimate the total number of steps by calculating the number of steps as a sum:

```
 n                    n
---                  ---
\     n-1            \    1
/     ---    = n-1 * /   ---
---    i             ---  i
i=1                  i=1
```

We can here use the Stirling approximation: we know that the integral if *1/i* will be between the sum of *1/(i+1)* and *1/i*.

The integral of *1/i*, so we approximate this as:

```
 n         n
---        /\
\    1     |    1
/   ---  ≈ |   --- dx  = log(n) - log(1)
---  i    \/    x
i=1        1
```

So that means that the total number of steps is, in terms of big oh *O(n* log *n)*.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of your code is `O(n log n)`. Inside the first for loop, the complexity is `O(n/i)` which in total we have:

```
O(n/1) + O(n/2) + ...+ O(n/i)+...+O(1)
```

Is equal to:

```
n O( 1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n ) = n O(log(n)) = O(n log(n))
```

Comment: No it's not. The outer for loop is O(n). Isn't it?

Comment: It is, times the inner loop O(n) because the step is 1

Comment: O(n) happens only one time, it the very first iteration of the first loop.