# Analyzing Running time of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Are there any written rules to determine runtime of a code?
What would be the arithmethic actions that I have to use in outer loops and inner loops?
A method in java language for example:

```
public static void mystery1(int n){
int k=n;// here I know that it’s O(1)
while(k>2){//O(k)
System.out.println(k);
k=(int)(Math.pow(k,1/3));
}
}

public static void dunno1(int n){
int i,j;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){// Do I use multiplication between those loops?
   for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
       mystery1(n)n
   }
 }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What has your research shown? Moreover, we can expect this to be a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the runtime of your program (java) using `System.nanoTime()`:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

.....your program....

long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println(totalTime);
```

And regarding the complexity of nested `for` loops you can see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop).