# What is the time complexity for multiple nested for loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

How to calculate time complexity for multiple nested loops? I have done this code but get confused about the time complexity of this!

```
for(i=0; i<max; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<max; j++)
    {
        a[i][j]= rand()%2;
    }
}

for(i=0; i<max; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<max; j++)
    {

        if(a[j][i]==1)
        {
            inD++;
        }
    }
}
for(i=0; i<max; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<max; j++)
    {
         if(a[i][j]==1)
         {
             outD++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://c-faq.com/lib/notveryrand.html.

Answer (score 0):

You have three loops. Let's take the first one.

The outer loop is running `max` times, and each pass through that loop is running the inner loop `max` times, making `max * max` calls to `a[i][j]= rand()%2;` in total. Each call generates a random number: I don't know what the cost of this is but it's independent of `max`. The cost of this loop is `O(max^2)`.

The other two loops have similar complexity except each inner call is essentially constant time since they're just increments.

Assuming they run one after the other, the whole thing is `O(max^2 + max^2 + max^2) = O(max^2)`.

This answer spells it out in a bit more detail: [Time complexity of nested for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop)

Comment: `R` is independent of `max`, so it's not relevant to the asymptotic complexity of the loop. No matter how big it might be, it *is* a constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; the rand()%2 function generates a number 0 or 1;

Comment: @chepner Yes, agreed. Answer modified.

Comment: Ok -- as @chepner points out it doesn't affect the complexity.