# What time complexity does the following code have?

Tags: python, time-complexity, spyder, complexity-theory

I am confused with the time complexity of the following code and I need all the help I can get because I'm struggling to figure it out.

The code goes as follows:

```
def herhalen(s,p):
    pc = 0
    while pc < len(s):
       pd = pc + 1
       while pd < len(s):
          if s[pd] == s[pc]:
             x = 0
             while pd + x < len(s) and x < p and s[pc + x] == s[pd + x]:
                x += 1
             if x ==p:
                return True
          pd += 1
       pc += 1
    return False
```

Comment: I have updated my answer and added the same code rewritten in a bit better way, which, however, helps to both easier understand time complexity and even find a bug! Remember to check out the difference between the snippets

Comment: I would encourage you to use more **meaningful** variable names as well as more (or at least some) **comments**. This not only benefits you when you are going over your code in the future but it also helps the community of Stack Overflow to better understand *your* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the elements of `s`. If, for instance, all elements of `s` are equal, then your condition `if s[pd] == s[pc]` will always be true, which will in turn affect the overall complexity. If, however, all elements of `s` are distinct, then `s[pd] == s[pc]` will only be true when the `pd` and `pc` hold the same value and therefore pointing to the same element in `s`.

#### Example 1 - Unique elements

```
s = [i for i in range(20)] #[0,1,2,...,19]
pc = 0
while pc < len(s):
    pd = pc + 1
    while pd < len(s):
        if s[pd] == s[pc]:
            print(pd)
        pd += 1
    pc += 1
```

In this scenario, the `print` function is never executed.

#### Example 2 - Identical elements

```
s = [0 for i in range(20)] #[0,0,...,0]
pc = 0
print_counter = 1
while pc < len(s):
    pd = pc + 1
    while pd < len(s):
        if s[pd] == s[pc]:
            print(print_counter)
            print_counter += 1
        pd += 1
    pc += 1
```

In this scenario, the `print` function got executed 190 times which is O(n^2).

#### Note

- Note that for your code, you have an additional loop that you have to consider.
- Also note that there exist more scenarios where the elements of `s` are neither all equal or all unique.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it helped me so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

Let's assume `N` is `len(s)`

The outer loop has `O(N)` complexity because `pc` takes all values from `0` to `len(s) - 1`. The second loop has the same complexity: although `pd` begins from `pc + 1`, not from `0`, the two loops together will have the complexity `O(N * N / 2) = O(N^2)`. The inner loop will have the `O(min(N, P))` complexity (where `P` is the `p` variable from your function) because the loop will end either when `pd + x` reaches `len(s)` or when `x` reaches `p`

So, assuming `P` is not too small, if I am not mistaken, the overall complexity is `O(N^3)`

If you are having difficulties understanding why do the inner loops (starting from the outer loop iterable instead of `0`) multiply complexity by `N`, not something smaller, please, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop)

## Important note

By the way, I guess it would be much easier for you to understand the complexity by yourself if you were using `for` loops instead of `while`s. I would rewrite the code in the following way (also contains some minor style improvements):

```py
def herhalen(s, p):
    for pc in range(len(s)):
       for pd in range(pc + 1, len(s)):
          if s[pd] == s[pc]:
             for x in range(p):
                 if pd + x < len(s) or s[pc + x] == s[pd + x]:
                     break
             else:
                return True
    return False
```

Use all the power of the language you are writing in :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @Escaloetje, oops, oh my god, I just figured out I was wrong. There was no bug in your code, it was my mistake when rewriting it. Sorry, I have updated the code, should work fine now