# Type mismatch (error 13) when inputting formula within loop

Tags: vba, loops, formula, type-mismatch

I'm writing a script to do some calculations within a loop as well as keep the formula in the cell. I ran into this error but don't know what the cause of this. The certain thing is there is no #N/A or Error in the cell, all the cells have numeric data. Here is the script I wrote:

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = workbooks("A.xlsx")
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lRow as Long
Dim i as Long

For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
lRow=sh.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 to lRow -1
sh.Range("M" & i+1).Formula = "=K" & i + "L" & i
Next i
Next sh
```

Can someone suggest any improvement or solution for this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: Think the `+` needs to be `"+ L"`

Comment: You don't need the inner loop to do this: `sh.Range("M2:M" & lRow - 1).Formula = "=K2+L2"`

Comment: Hi Warcupine, I thought so but still the same.

Comment: `"=K" & i & "+L" & i` but really, skip the loop.

Comment: Hi BigBen. so the formula is fixed as "k2+L2" for this column?

Comment: Try it. Excel will update the row number down the rows.

Comment: Any reason for skipping the loop? More efficient and cleaner?

Comment: *Way* more efficient.

Comment: [Some reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526728/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop) on why you want to avoid nesting loops when possible.

Comment: Sorry @Warcupine, I think I didn't understand your suggestion at the first place, it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen, you are correct, both suggestions work but yes, more efficient without looping.