# Using Big O Notation, what is the correct label for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, nested, time-complexity, big-o

I am curious. What is the correct way to describe this using Big-O Notation?

```
var prices = [100, 180, 260, 590, 40, 310, 535, 10, 5, 3];
var biggest_profit = 0;
  
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    var first_price = prices[i];
  
    for (var j = i + 1; j <= prices.length; j++) {
      // do something here
    }
}
```

This is the bit that throws me off:

```
j = i + 1
```

Every time we go through `i`, the `j` becomes shorter and shorter.

What is the correct name for this pattern in Big O Notation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Big-O of a nested loop, where number of iterations in the inner loop is determined by the current iteration of the outer loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362059/what-is-the-big-o-of-a-nested-loop-where-number-of-iterations-in-the-inner-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Sigma notation to calculate the number of visits of the inner loop (*"do something here"*)

[image]

Where `(*)` follows from a [summation rule made famous by the rumour that Gauss once derived it on-the-spot as a young student](https://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/).

Answer (score 5):

If `do something here` is an `O(1)` operation, the whole algorithm is `O(N^2)`.

**How to compute?** (Thanks to @dfri for error catching)

Outer loop:  `i: [0->N-1]`

Inner loop:  `j: [i+1->N]`

Total= `N + (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + ... + 1 = N(N+1)/2 = O(N^2)`

Comment: How do you derive the Total from the outer and inner loop running times?

Comment: To be picky, the outer loop runs from `i+1` to `N-1` (not `N`), yielding a total inner loop visit count of `N(N+1)/2` (the end result in terms of asymptotic analysis is naturally the same, though). @stackoverflowuser2010: I've added an alternative answer for those possibly interested in more details of the loop count calculation.

Comment: @dfri Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the big O of this algorithm, just imagine a shape:
In each iteration of outer for loop, we have a row, made of small squares. Each square is one iteration of inner for loop. So for first iteration of outer for loop, we would have a full line of squares.
The second row, will lose one of the squares.
And the third row, will lose another one.
...
The last row, will just have a single square.
Finally we will have this shape:

```
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜_____
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜_______
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜________
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜_________
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜__________
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜___________
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜____________
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜_____________
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜______________
⬜⬜⬜⬜_______________
⬜⬜⬜________________
⬜⬜_________________
⬜__________________
```

This is half of a big square. So its area is:
prices.length * (prices.length - 1) * 1/2.
And we can remove "-1" because it is little enough.
And the result:
Prices.length * prices.length * 1/2
The 1/2 isn't important in Big O. So the algorithm has a O(n^2) time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

```
var prices = [100, 180, 260, 590, 40, 310, 535, 10, 5, 3];
var biggest_profit = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {  // outer loop
    var first_price = prices[i];

    for (var j = i + 1; j <= prices.length; j++) {  // inner loop
        // do something here
    }
}
```

In the first iteration of the outer loop (i = 0), the inner loop executes `N` times.

In the second iteration of the outer loop (i = 1), the inner loop executes `N - 1` times.

In the third iteration of the outer loop (i = 2), the inner loop executes `N - 2` times.

.
.
.

In the `N - 2`th iteration of the outer loop (i = N - 3), the inner loop executes `3` times.

In the `N - 1`th iteration of the outer loop (i = N - 2), the inner loop executes `2` times.

In the last (`N`th) iteration of the outer loop (i = N - 1), the inner loop executes `1` time.

Therefore, the total number of times this code executes is

`N` + `N - 1` + `N - 2` + `N - 3` + … + `2` + `1`

= `1` + `2` + … + `N - 3` + `N - 2` + `N - 1` + `N`

Substituting this in the Sum of Natural numbers Formula,

= `(N)(N + 1) / 2`

= `((N^2) + N) / 2`

= `O(N^2)`, assuming `// do something here` executes in constant time `O(1)`.

——————

Also, do take a look at these

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805214/17112163
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71146522/17112163
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69821878/17112163
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537431/17112163
5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72046933/17112163