# How to find runtime of algorithm in big-o

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, runtime, big-o

```
public void do() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            // do something

    for (int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i += 2)
        for (int j = 1; j < columns - 1; j += 2) {
            // do something

    for (int i =  50; i > 0; i--)
        // do something

    for (int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < columns - 1; j++)
            // do something
}
```

In this case rows and column would equal:

`rows = (size * 10) + 1;`
`columns = rows + 10;`

where `size` (n) is 1, 2, 4, or 8.

Since the `rows` and `columns` variables will increase with respect to the size and each loop will run over the rows and then the columns inside the loop can I say that this function would run in **O(n^2)**?

I am fairly new with the whole complexity of an algorithm would love some input on this. Thank so much.

Comment: No because `n` isn't defined.

Comment: Sorry, I defined it. Wouldn't the size be n?

Comment: You can follow this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Directly answering your code :
[What is the Big-O of a nested loop, where number of iterations in the inner loop is determined by the current iteration of the outer loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362059/what-is-the-big-o-of-a-nested-loop-where-number-of-iterations-in-the-inner-loop)

N is for one loop, so two nested = N^2, etc. If there is 2 instructions in the nested loop, it would be in reality 2N^2, but the multiplication by two is uselses, so N^2 anyway.

Comment: Cheers, your attached answer helped as well.

Comment: You should flag the question as duplicate.