# Calculating time complexity with big O

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o

I have an assignment I am not sure with; I have to calculate the time complexity of the following code:

```
int a[][] = new int[m][n];        //O(1)
int w = 0;                        //O(1)
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)       //O(n)
    for (int j = 0; j <n; j++)    //O(n)
         if (a[i] [j] % 2 == 0)   //O(logn)
         w++;                     //O(1)
```

So from my O estimations I add them up:

O(1) + O(1) + O(n) * ( O(n) * ( O(logn) + O(1) / 2 ) ) 
O(1) + O(1) + O(n) * ( O(nlogn) + O(n) / 2 )
O(1) + O(1) + (O(n<sup>2</sup>logn) + O(n<sup>2</sup>) / 2)
=O(n<sup>2</sup>logn)

I'm not sure if my train of thought is correct, could somebody help?

Comment: That log is wrong. The complete complexity is just quadratic. (The if is just a constant operation assuming modulo is constant)

Comment: @sascha it's not quadratic.

Comment: @sascha Oh I see... I had in my notes somewhere my lecturer mentioned that because there was a chance for the variables to be %2 and it is o(logn) for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)       //O(m)
    for (int j = 0; j <n; j++)    //O(n)
         if (a[i] [j] % 2 == 0)   //O(1)
         w++;                     //O(1)
```

So the total complexity in terms of [big-o](/questions/tagged/big-o) is:

`O(m)*(O(n) + O(1) + O(1)) = O(m)*O(n) = O(m*n)`.

Comment: You're adding apples to oranges. You cannot tell the `int a[][] = new int[m][n];` is `O(1)` while `for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)` is `O(m)`. It's really a super non-scientific and misleading way to do the Big-O complexity analysis.

Comment: @zerkms I agree. It's `O(mn)`. Didn't think about the initialization.

Comment: Not only that - my point is that you cannot simply add arbitrarily put `O()` approximations together. Simple reason: why do you assume `new int[m][n]` is fixed time?

Comment: Now it's even worse :-) I would not sum them at all. But I'm not insisting on  it :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)  //O(m)
  {   
    for (int j = 0; j <n; j++) //O(n)
    {
      // your code
    }
  }
```

So the i loop will go on m times, and for the j loop would run n times.
So in total the code will go on `m*n` times which would be its time complexity:  `O(m.n)`

Comment: so the o(m) and o(n) variables should be treated independently as opposed to o(n^2) for running the for loop twice?

Comment: if the for loop is run twice(each time upto n times), then there will be two independent O(n) computations(considering it's a loop within a loop). O(n) for the outer loop and O(n) for the inner loop, resulting in O(n^2).

Comment: But if it's two separate for loops, each running upto n , then it will be O(n) +O(n) = O(2n) which is the same as O(n)

Answer (score -1):

The final complexity is O(n^2)

Your logic is close except...

```
int a[][] = new int[m][n];        //O(1)
int w = 0;                        //O(1)
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)       //O(n)
    for (int j = 0; j <n; j++)    //O(n)
         if (a[i] [j] % 2 == 0)   //O(1)
         w++;                     //O(1)
```

Your if statement embedded in your second for loop is simply referencing an element in an array and doing a basic comparison. This is of time complexity O(1). Also, typically you would not consider initializing variables in a time complexity problem.

Comment: Wrong ! The first loop goes until m, not n !

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail It's the same function-class.

Comment: Is this answer wrong then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362059/what-is-the-big-o-of-a-nested-loop-where-number-of-iterations-in-the-inner-loop

Comment: Your link is okay, it is going from 0 to N, and for each i, it is again going from 0 to N ;)
But here, the first loop goes until M

Comment: Yep it sure does. Thanks for the correction @ValentinMontmirail