# Big-O Analysis of Arbitrarily Nested For Loops?

Tags: big-o

Say I have k for loops nested in the following fashion:

```
for a = 1 to n:
    for b = 1 to n-a:
        for c = 1 to n-a-b:
            for d = 1 to n-a-b-c:
                O(1)
```

for any arbitrary k, but all k of these loops "share" the limit of n iterations with each other, is the big-O complexity still O(n^k)? Or is it some order below that?

Edit: [What is the Big-O of a nested loop, where number of iterations in the inner loop is determined by the current iteration of the outer loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362059) is indeed asking something similar but it wasn't asking (nor does the answer address) if additional levels of nesting will change anything.

Dmitry's answer explains it very well for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Big-O of a nested loop, where number of iterations in the inner loop is determined by the current iteration of the outer loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362059/what-is-the-big-o-of-a-nested-loop-where-number-of-iterations-in-the-inner-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's sum them all up: using *induction* you can find out that numbers of loops (for large `n > k`) are:

```
  1. n 
  2. n * (n - 1) / 2 
  3. n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 6
  ...
  k. n * (n - 1) * ... * (n - k + 1) / k!
  ...
```

As you can see the complexity is `O(n**k)` as you've conjured for any `k` providing that `n` is large enough (`n > k`).