# Time complexity of the code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Sorry if this question is a duplicate ,or is kind of stupid ,but I'm really new to algorithm development)
Can you explain me what is the complexity of following piece of code

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        do stuff...
    }
}
```

is the complexity of this code `n^2` or `nlogn`?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Big-O of a nested loop, where number of iterations in the inner loop is determined by the current iteration of the outer loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362059/what-is-the-big-o-of-a-nested-loop-where-number-of-iterations-in-the-inner-loop)

Comment: Please stop malforming your own code. I've had to roll this back 3 times now

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is `O(n^2)`.

For first iteration of outer loop, inner loop will iterate `0` times

For second iteration of outer loop, inner loop will iterate `1` times.

For third iteration of outer loop, inner loop will iterate `2` times.

.........

For `n`th iteration of outer loop, inner loop will iterate `n - 1` times.

Total number of iterations = `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ...... + (n - 1)`

We know, the sum of arithmetic series

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ..... + (n - 2) + (n - 1) + n = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
```

So,

```
 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ...... + (n - 1) 
 = (n * (n - 1)) / 2 
 ~ n^2
```

Considering the `do stuff` phase will execute in constant time, the overall time complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Why do you divide by 2?