# Big O for nested loops

Tags: loops, big-o, nested-loops

Another Big O question, yet I can't wrap my head around it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n * n; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            //do sth
```

My thought: The outer loop is `O(n)`. The middle is `O(n^2)`. However, the inner depends on the middle, so for each j, k is gonna run `1+2+3+...+n = [n^2(n^2+1)]/2` which is the same as `O(n^4)`.
So instead the middle runs about `O(n^2)`, it actually runs `O(n^4)`. Which would result in `O(n^5)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Also, this is roughly answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362059/what-is-the-big-o-of-a-nested-loop-where-number-of-iterations-in-the-inner-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total amount of loop iterations is Θ(n<sup>5</sup>).

[image: 1]